# Search Appointments in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Im trying to code a script that read my excel sheets and compare the date with the date of appointments in Outlook.

I dont know why my code dont find any OLAppointment Item to compare their date with my dte on the sheet...

See the code below

```
Public Function CheckAppointment(ByVal argCheckDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oApptItem As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As Object
    Dim oObject As Object
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("aa")
    CheckAppointment = False
    For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
    MsgBox oObject
    If (oObject.Class = OLAppointment) Then
      Set oApptItem = oObject
        If oApptItem.Start = argCheckDate Then
            CheckAppointment = True
        End If
      End If
    Next oObject

    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing

End Function

Public Sub Driver()

    Dim dtCheck As Date
    Dim sbCheck As String

    dtCheck = DateValue("23/11/2013") + TimeValue("09:00:00")


    If CheckAppointment(dtCheck) Then
        MsgBox "Appointment found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Appointment not found", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

I have an appointment created on the calendar "aa" on 23/11/2013 but when i try to search it with my macro always give me "appointment not found". Also ive tried to show with "Msgbox" the properties of the appointments found with:

```
Set oFolder = oNameSpace.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("aa")
CheckAppointment = False
For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
MsgBox oObject.Subject
```

but dont go anyway :\

Sry for my poor english.

Comment: where is this calendar `aa` located? under `Mailbox` or `Calendar`?

Comment: @PatricK  9 is olFolderCalendar. There may be an msdn url with the enumeration but I have this http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Outlook_external_en.html

Comment: I know `olFolderCalendar = 9`, just wanted to make sure your `aa` calendar is under the Default Calendar. Since you can have calendar folders right under mailbox. Your code will work if you add the line to define `olAppointment`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not define what `OLAppointment` is. Since this is macro in Excel, you need to define Outlook internal constants.

```
Public Function CheckAppointment(ByVal argCheckDate As Date) As Boolean

    Const olAppointment = 26 ' <== Added this line and your code worked.
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oApptItem As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As Object
    Dim oObject As Object
    On Error Resume Next ' No appointment was found since you have this line and olAppointmnet wasn't defined.

    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("aa")
    CheckAppointment = False
    For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
        MsgBox oObject
        If (oObject.Class = olAppointment) Then ' <== This is why you need to define it first
            Set oApptItem = oObject
            If oApptItem.Start = argCheckDate Then
                CheckAppointment = True
                Exit For ' <== Added this exit for loop to improve performance
            End If
        End If
    Next oObject

    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub Driver()
    Dim dtCheck As Date
    Dim sbCheck As String

    dtCheck = DateValue("4/11/2013") + TimeValue("09:00:00")
    If CheckAppointment(dtCheck) Then
        MsgBox "Appointment found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Appointment not found", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Your code works, tested with calendar named `aa` under the default `Calendar`.