# finding specific appointments in agenda through excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, automation, appointment

I have an excel file in which i register action of employees.

This is the following design:
ID      Datum       Type    Typedatail  Metadata    Regdata hours

- 3767  01/04/2018  SN  VM  64  05/01/2018  4
- 3767  01/04/2018  SN  NM  65  05/01/2018  4
- 3767  03/04/2018  SN  VM  66  05/01/2018  4
- 3767  03/04/2018  SN  NM  67  05/01/2018  4
- 3767  04/04/2018  SN  VM  68  05/01/2018  4
- 3767  04/04/2018  SN  NM  69  05/01/2018  4
- 3767  07/04/2018  CA      70  05/01/2018  8
- 3767  08/04/2018  CA      71  05/01/2018  8
- 3767  09/04/2018  CA      72  05/01/2018  8
- 3683  12/01/2018  OU-     73  05/01/2018  -8

I need to put them into a calender also to distribute this knowledge.
!(https://ibb.co/hQmOxR)

But at times i need to edit those. (change or delete those)

i have found the following as a base
[Search Appointments in excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756315/search-appointments-in-excel-with-vba)

This finds them eventually but this runs through ALL the appointments, which is unneeded as i know on which date the appointment is set.

> Therefore i want to restrict the range but i make a fault with it, that i can not figure out.

Base find appointment

```
    Public Function CheckAppointment(ByVal argCheckDate As Date, ByVal argTikNummer As Integer) As Boolean

    Const olAppointment = 26 ' <== Added this line and your code worked.
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oApptItem As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As Object
    Dim oObject As Object

    Dim strRestriction As String        'opmaak zoekbeperking


    On Error Resume Next ' No appointment was found since you have this line and olAppointmnet wasn't defined.

    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 'oNameSpace.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders(olFolderCalendar)
    CheckAppointment = False
    For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
        'MsgBox oObject
        If (oObject.Class = olAppointment) Then ' <== This is why you need to define it first
            Set oApptItem = oObject

            If oApptItem.Start = argCheckDate And InStr(oApptItem.Body, argTikNummer) Then
                MsgBox oApptItem.Body
                CheckAppointment = True
                Exit For ' <== Added this exit for loop to improve performance
            End If
        End If
    Next oObject

    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub Driver()
    Dim dtCheck As Date
    Dim intTikNummer As Integer
    Dim sbCheck As String
Sheets("blad1").Select
Dim i As Long
i = 2


    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""                                   'voorlopig test omgeving. Moet worden omgevormd tot een single entry test
        dtCheck = Cells(i, 2) '+ TimeValue("09:00:00")
        intTikNummer = Cells(i, 1)
        If CheckAppointment(dtCheck, intTikNummer) Then
            MsgBox "Appointment found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation            'dummy uitkomst verslag. Moet worden vervangen door een opdracht
        Else
            MsgBox "Appointment not found", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation        'dummy uitkomst verslag. Moet worden vervangen door een opdracht
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub



`
```

Base restriction example (outlook)
        Sub FindAppts()

```
        Dim myStart As Date
        Dim myEnd As Date
        Dim oCalendar As Outlook.folder
        Dim oItems As Outlook.items
        Dim oItemsInDateRange As Outlook.items
        Dim oFinalItems As Outlook.items
        Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
        Dim strRestriction As String

        myStart = Date
        myEnd = DateAdd("d", 30, myStart)

        Debug.Print "Start:", myStart
        Debug.Print "End:", myEnd

        'Construct filter for the next 30-day date range
        strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" &; _
        Format$(myStart, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") _
        &; "' AND [End] <= '" &; _
        Format$(myEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") &; "'"
        'Check the restriction string
        Debug.Print strRestriction
        Set oCalendar = Application.session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
        Set oItems = oCalendar.items
        oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
        oItems.Sort "[Start]"
        'Restrict the Items collection for the 30-day date range
        Set oItemsInDateRange = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)
        'Construct filter for Subject containing 'team'
        Const PropTag  As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
        strRestriction = "@SQL=" &; Chr(34) &; PropTag _
            &; "0x0037001E" &; Chr(34) &; " like '%team%'"
        'Restrict the last set of filtered items for the subject
        Set oFinalItems = oItemsInDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)
        'Sort and Debug.Print final results
        oFinalItems.Sort "[Start]"
        For Each oAppt In oFinalItems
            Debug.Print oAppt.Start, oAppt.Subject
        Next
    End Sub

`
```

### I came to the following result (through example)

```
Public Function CheckAppointment(ByVal argCheckDate As Date, ByVal argTikNummer As Integer) As Boolean

    Const olAppointment = 26 ' <== Added this line and your code worked.
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oApptItem As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFolderA As Object
    Dim oFolderB As Object
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As Object
    Dim oObject As Object

    Dim myStart, myEnd As Date
    Dim strRestriction As String        'opmaak zoekbeperking
    'Construct filter for day date range
    myStart = Format(argCheckDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'argcheckdate
    myEnd = DateAdd("d", 1, myStart)
    myEnd = Format(myEnd, "dd/mm/yyyy")  'Argcheckdate
    Debug.Print "Start:", myStart
    Debug.Print "End:", myEnd

    strRestriction = "[Start] = '" & myStart & "' AND [End] = '" & myEnd & "'"



    On Error Resume Next ' No appointment was found since you have this line and olAppointmnet wasn't defined.

    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 'oNameSpace.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders(olFolderCalendar)
    CheckAppointment = False

    'Restrict the Items collection for the 30-day date range
    Set oFolderA = oFolder.Restrict(strRestriction)


    For Each oObject In oFolderA.Items
        MsgBox oObject & " : " & oObject.Start & " : " & myStart & " - " & myEnd
        If (oObject.Class = olAppointment) Then ' <== This is why you need to define it first
            Set oApptItem = oObject

            If oApptItem.Start = argCheckDate And InStr(oApptItem.Body, argTikNummer) Then
                MsgBox oApptItem.Body
                CheckAppointment = True
                Exit For ' <== Added this exit for loop to improve performance
            End If
        End If
    Next oObject

    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFolderA = Nothing
    Set oFolderB = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing
End Function
```

---

I end up with an empty `oApptItem` yet If `oApptItem.Start = argCheckDate` And `InStr(oApptItem.Body, argTikNummer)` trigger true despite the appointments not being in the list.

The above code is meant as a base to be used to edit or delete an appointment.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering a calendar is tricky and this is compounded by not turning off `On Error Resume Next`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckAppointment_test()

    ' Appointment date
    Dim argCheckDate As String
    argCheckDate = "2018-01-05"

    ' Text in body of appointment
    Dim argTikNummer As Long
    argTikNummer = 3767

    Dim result As Boolean
    MsgBox CheckAppointment(argCheckDate, argTikNummer) & vbCr & " Done."

End Sub


Public Function CheckAppointment(ByVal argCheckDate As Date, ByVal argTikNummer As Integer) As Boolean

    ' Not required as Outlook must be referenced
    '  to use olFolderCalendar later
    'Const olAppointment = 26

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oApptItem As Object

    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFolderA As Object

    Dim oObject As Object

    Dim myStart, myEnd As Date
    Dim strRestriction As String

    'Construct filter for day date range
    'myStart = Format(argCheckDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'argcheckdate
    myStart = Format(argCheckDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") 'argcheckdate

    myEnd = DateAdd("d", 1, myStart)
    'myEnd = Format(myEnd, "dd/mm/yyyy")  'Argcheckdate
    myEnd = Format(myEnd, "yyyy-mm-dd")  'Argcheckdate

    Debug.Print "Start:", myStart
    Debug.Print "End:", myEnd

    'strRestriction = "[Start] = '" & myStart & "' AND [End] = '" & myEnd & "'"
    strRestriction = "[Start] <= '" & myEnd & "' AND [End] >= '" & myStart & "'"
    Debug.Print strRestriction

    ' Misuse causes insurmountable problems as errors are hidden
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    ' Mandatory with On Error Resume Next to stop bypassing errors
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Handle error bypassed above, if any
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    CheckAppointment = False



    ' *******

    Dim oFolderItems As Object
    Set oFolderItems = oFolder.items

    ' Strange behaviour if this is not used
    oFolderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True

    oFolderItems.Sort "[Start]"

    ' *******


    'Restrict the Items collection for the specified date range
    Set oFolderA = oFolderItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

    'For Each oObject In oFolderA.items
    For Each oObject In oFolderA

        Debug.Print oObject.Subject & " : " & oObject.Start

        If (oObject.Class = olAppointment) Then

            Set oApptItem = oObject

            Debug.Print "oApptItem.Start: " & oApptItem.Start
            Debug.Print "Formatted oApptItem.Start: " & Format(oApptItem.Start, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            Debug.Print "argCheckDate: " & argCheckDate

            ' Not true unless oApptItem.Start is formatted to match format of argCheckDate
            '  Should not be necessary if the filter is working correctly
            'If oApptItem.Start = argCheckDate Then

                Debug.Print InStr(oApptItem.body, argTikNummer)
                If InStr(oApptItem.body, argTikNummer) Then
                    MsgBox oApptItem.Subject & vbCr & oApptItem.body
                    CheckAppointment = True

                    ' Do not exit if there can be multiple appointments
                    'Exit For

                End If

            'End If

        End If

    Next oObject

    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFolderA = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This piece of code works. i get a result from it. But there is something peculiar with it i can not yet pinpoint.


Say i check on the 18th. I expect and need to get a result to find the previous and/or next day.
have an entry on the 17th

Comment: having an entry on the 17th i can not find, having one on the 19th i do find.

Comment: With `argCheckDate = "2018-01-17"` and  `myEnd = DateAdd("d", 3, myStart)` and `Exit For` commented out, you should find all instances from 17th to 19th.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i know that that would be a work around. but thing is, why can i find the appointment on the 19th, but not the one on the 17th, even with the exit for blotted out.

Comment: Appears to work as intended for me. I think this falls to you to debug, to find the issue in the appointment or the logic. You can search the site for questions with different solutions. Some are collected here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-filter