# How to get archived meetings from the outlook calender using vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am working on a vba macro in Excel. All meetings from the outlook calendar, (in a given time period), are read and written down into a new table.

Everything works except for archived meetings. Archived meetings have some strange properties which do not match the properties from meetings which are not archived. This leads to runtime errors.

I have tried to unarchive every meeting. After I did so it worked but since other people want to use my macro, it should work with archived meetings too.

I am sure the problem only occurs when you try to read out archived meetings because I changed my code in order to skip the errors and every non archived meeting behaved how it should.

I could not find anyone on the internet with the same problem so I'm asking this question here.

```
'Here I read out of the Oulook calendar 

'---------------------------------------------------'

    'Create filter to restrict meetings to the start/end date

    '---------------------------------------------------'

    strRestriction = "[End] >= '" & _
    Format$(startDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm ") & "' AND [Start] <= '" & Format$(endDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm ") & "'"
    Set outlookCalendar = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(9)
    Set calendarItems = outlookCalendar.items
    calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    calendarItems.Sort "[Start]"
    nextRow = 1
    Set itemsInDateRange = calendarItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

'Here I write into the excel sheet 
For Each entry In itemsInDateRange

    With Sheets(sheetToWriteIn)
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
        sumInMinutes = sumInMinutes + durationOfOneMeeting ' summs every meeting up to return a sum at the end of the programm
        .Cells(nextRow, "D").Value = durationOfOneMeeting
        .Cells(nextRow, "A").Value = entry.Subject
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = entry.start 'The error ocures here or at entry.start
        .Cells(nextRow, "C").Value = entry.End
        .Cells(nextRow, "E").Value = entry.Location
        End If
    End With
Next
```

When I try to get the start date from an archived meeting (which works perfectly fine for "normal" meetings) I get an:

> `Object does not support property`

or

> `function Runtime error 438`

Comment: do you have the same issue with this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57426779/11167163) ? I added the time Spent and not the hour of start and the hour of end..

Comment: Edited The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57426779/11167163) So it fit to your needs, do not hesitate to leave me some feedbacks if something doesn't work for you as excepted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a try :

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListAppointments()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olApt As Object
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date

    FromDate = CDate("08/25/2017")
    ToDate = Now()

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9) 'olFolderCalendar
    NextRow = 2

    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of the sheet here
        .Range("A1:G1").Value = Array("Project", "Date", "Time spent", "Location" , "Categories" , "Start Hour" , "End Hour")
        For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
            If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
                .Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
                .Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.End - olApt.Start
                .Cells(NextRow, "C").NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
                .Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Location
                .Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.Categories
                .Cells(NextRow, "F").Value = olApt.Start
                .Cells(NextRow, "G").Value = olApt.End
                NextRow = NextRow + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next olApt
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good idea.

Comment: Why ? I tested this and it goes quite fast ... what do you propose so i can try to improve this

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sadly this does not work if an apointment is archived...

Comment: @TourEiffel If you haven't run across a method of reducing the number of iterations see as an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174126/1571407. There will be no noticeable time saving unless the number of items is very large, or your code has millions of users.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to retrieve all Outlook appointment items from the folder that meets the predefined condition, you need to [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866960.aspx) the items in ascending order and set the [IncludeRecurrences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866969.aspx) to true. You will not catch recurrent appointments if you don’t do this before using the `Find` or `Restrict` method!

Secondly, Microsoft doesn’t recommend using the `Count` property in case you set the `IncludeRecurrences` property. The Count property may return unexpected results and cause an infinite loop.

Thirdly, I would recommend using the do/while or foreach loops for iterating found items. The for loop can’t be used because the `Count` property of the Items class may return unexpected results.